# how can I change the tint color of the barButtonItems in the STPPaymentOptionsViewController and STPAddCardViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, stripe-payments, uinavigationbar

My goal is to be able to change the color the tint color of the bar button items in the Stripe integrated view controllers. The `STPCoreViewController` is responsible for basically all the STP view controllers but it says you shouldn't inherit it in your own app, plus even if you could the class isn't fully open, it has a public access level.

I know if it was any other view controller, you'd just set the navigation bar tint color to white, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get access to these bar button items.

The `STPViewControllers` can be either presented modally or pushed, right now I have the `STPPaymentOptionsViewController` being pushed when a button is pressed. When it loads, the vc looks like this :

[image: Payment Method]

For some weird reason it basically inherits the background color, text color, and font from the Vc it was pushed from, but it won't inherit the colors of the bar button items. The same thing happens with the Add Card Vc:

[image: add card vc]

Even when the vc is presented, it still presents full screen but the navigation bar title is large and black, and the background is white with the system blue bar button items. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the NavigationBar buttons with `accentColor` on an STPTheme instance: https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPTheme.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(cs)STPTheme(py)accentColor

Here is my example of me setting

`theme.accentColor = UIColor.red`

[image]